# What's the different between super and super() in java?

Tags: java, super

like this:

```
public class class1 {   
    public void xxx(){

        super.getXXX();

        super().getXXX();

    }
}
```

Comment: One is super and the other is super-duper. Seriously though does that compile? Why not post *real* code in your question? Code that is simple, but that actually compiles and demonstrates what you're asking?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You may be the duper in this case...? http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duper "a person who dupes another"

Comment: @gutch: you may be right on this one.

Comment: Again, your code **won't compile**. The `super()` constructor call can only be called in a constructor and only on the first line of the constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are used in a subclass as a way to invoke or refer to its superclass.

`super()` is a method call you make inside a constructor or inside an overridden method to invoke the superclass's constructor or the superclass's overridden method.  The super() call can also take arguments in these cases.

Note that since all classes by default at least inherit from Object, you can always call super() inside a constructor (it must be the first statement in the constructor though).  This super() call is in fact ordinarily inserted by the compiler into your no-arg constructor by default.

This can get tricky however if the superclass doesn't have a no-arg constructor though, in which case your call to super() will fail without the appropriate args.  A no-arg constructor is ordinarily generated by default however so you don't have to worry about it, but it won't be automatically generated if you've explicitly define another constructor with args, so that's when you may need to explicitly define one yourself.

`super` without the parens on the other hand is simply a reference to the superclass itself, like any other variable.  It can be used to invoke any accessible method in that class or to refer to any of the class's accessible fields, just like you would with any other reference.  Eg: `super.doSomething()` or `super.x`

Answer (score 5):

Every class in java has a Superclass. When you use the `super` keyword, you are referring to super class, and the dot operator on `super` will give you access to the Super class's properties and methods.

`super()` is the constructor of super class. When you override the constructor in a subclass, you have to call `super()` before you can execute your own logic, and if you don't, the compiler, on your behalf, will insert a call to the no-args constructor. (Sometimes, there isn't one, and the code fails in compilation)

While in Java, calling the constructor gives you an instance of the class, it isn't the same thing when you do a `super()`, because there isn't a separate instance of the super class getting created when you do a `super()`. Hence, while `MyClass().doSomething()` is a perfectly valid call, `super().doSomethingElse()` is not.

Comment: I have up-voted this as a correct answer. I'm not sure who or why someone down-voted ths.

Comment: *"... you have to call super() ..."* - Yes and no.  There has to be a call to a superclass constructor, but it *could be* an implicit one ... if there is an explicit or implicit no-args constructor in the superclass.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels This is not the problem about the code. Do you mean you can not understand, only because the code doesn't compile ?